# Is it possible to hack/edit a camera's software to add custom features?

Tags: camera, software, reverse-engineering, firmware

I am not a programmer but I am curious if it's possible to hack my Canon camera to be able to work in sync with a custom gimbal that I'm thinking of building. I want to add an object tracking feature in the camera and I want it to work in sync with the gimbal so that when a target locked object moves, the motorized gimbal will move the camera to keep it pointed towards the target locked object.

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, no. If you need a hardware mod for communications with the gimbal, even more no.

Comment: Adding object tracking will probably be more than the processor in the camera is built to do. Better option would be to use something like the Jetson and pipe the video output from the camera into it, then run OpenCV to do the object tracking/gimbal manipulation.

Comment: Hacking would be very difficult. There're many camera modules in the market. You should make your own software. That should be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky with Canon. You need to look at two projects :

**CHDK** : Small cameras.

https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/CHDK

**MagicLantern** : Digital reflex, "DSLR"

https://magiclantern.fm/

(Only older models are supported.)

You could build custom version of these firmwares with additional features. It is also possible to run scripts directly from CHDK or MagicLantern.